# Trouble creating "if then" Javascript statement to change background color of page

Tags: javascript, if-statement, random, background-color

I'm working on a project right now that requires we use Javascripts built in RNG to generate a number from 0-37, and then change the background color from blue to black if the number is odd, and blue to red if the number is even. I'm almost certain I've got the commands right, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Just looking for a second set of eyes to glance it over that might spot what I'm doing incorrectly.

here's the code that I'm using so far:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeColor () {
    if ( ('wheel' % 2) == 0) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
}

</script>

<body bgcolor="blue">



<p><font size="4" color="white"><b>First place a bet on a number or color. 
<br>Then, spin the wheel to see if you win.</b></font></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Spin the Wheel</button>

<font face="Jokerman" color="white" size="6"><p id="wheel"></p></font>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 38) + 0);
    document.getElementById("wheel").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The page loads correctly, the button to generate a number is working properly, but no matter what the result is, the background color remains blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your "commands" aren't right.

1. Here, you try to get the modulo from a simple JS string:

   ```
   if ('wheel' % 2 == 0) {
   ```

   which will actually result in `NaN`, and condition will always result in `false`.
2. You have declared and implemented `changeColor` function, but you actually never call it.

In order to make it work, you can simply combine your `changeColor` and `myFunction`.
Here is the working **demo**:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 38) + 0);
    document.getElementById("wheel").innerHTML = x;
  
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Spin the Wheel</button>

<p id="wheel" style="color: white;"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. And yeah, sorry about the "command" reference, I really am out of my element here. However, I'm still having trouble, because the requirements state that the background color has to start off as blue, and it seems that having the <body bgcolor="blue> is preventing the function you sent me from running on my html. Any ideas?

Comment: @ECHtoplasm Do not use `bgcolor`. It is deprecated and is not supported by HTML5. Use `CSS`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for sticking with this, its really helped out a lot. There's still some minor issues I'm having but you've been a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

Change your changeColor() method as shown below.

```
 function changeColor() {
        var x = document.getElementById("wheel").innerHTML;

        if ((parseInt(x) % 2) == 0) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your script should be in the bottom of the body of your page like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="blue"> 
 <p><font size="4" color="white"><b>First place a bet on a number or color. 
 <br>Then, spin the wheel to see if you win.</b></font></p> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Spin the Wheel</button>

<font face="Jokerman" color="white" size="6"><p id="wheel"></p></font>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 38) + 0);
    document.getElementById("wheel").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeColor () {
    if ( ('wheel' % 2) == 0) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With my level of skill in JS and jQuery thats all i can help you with. Hope its a start!

Comment: It is not necessary, in this case.

Comment: `'wheel' % 2` does not make any sense because its always `NaN`